# Webpack plugin for module friendly names (path instead of a number)

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

During the hot update in webpack development server in console I see these messages:

```
[HMR] Updated modules: 
[HMR]  - 1009 
[HMR]  - 1007
```

I would rather see the path names in there and I remember there was a plugin for that, but could not find it in Google.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

In webpack 4 it's just on by default when mode is set to `development`

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
}
```

and can be controlled directly as well:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    namedModules: true
  }
};
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** (for older webpack versions)

I have found it myself, it's part of `webpack` itself it seems.
here is how you add it:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    ...
]
```

Now the module names in console and in the source will be like that:

```
[HMR] Updated modules:
[HMR]  - ./../MyModule1.jsx
[HMR]  - ./../MyModule2.jsx
```

Comment: Or just set mode to development, see: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/